# jQuery dialog modal not performing $.post( function(){}) after ALERT

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to create a jquery-Modal based, pop up FORM, which i coded Successfully & its also submitting data to MySQL table, using $.post().
But as per code below, its not doing anything after ALERT.
Its not RESETTING form value , not FADEOUT, not AUTO-CLOSE.

jQuery CODE is :

```
$.post("addnewpage.php", { newPageName1: newPageName }, function(data) {
  alert("New Page added :" + data).fadeOut("slow");
  $('#newpageform')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
  //$("#lean_overlay").trigger("click"); 
  $("span.modal_close > i").trigger("click"); // to auto-close leanModal window
  //close_modal("modal");
});
```

Any Guesses, why ? Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Any errors in the console?Are your selectors finding elements?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
$('form')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
```

Answer (score 0):

`alert("New Page added :" + data).fadeOut("slow");` is where things go wrong in my opinion.

Since `alert` is a function on the `window` object you can't chain jQuery functions at this stage.

You'll have to get your jQuery object first in order to execute a jQuery function `fadeOut`.

```
$(".ui-dialog").fadeOut("slow"); // or something like that
```

Comment: Tim is saying that `alert` isn't a jQuery function, which is why you can't chain other jQuery functions to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `fadeOut` function on your alert, you need to call it on a DOM Object. And jQuery `reset` function does not exist...